# Ionic 2 : File Opener return empty file

Tags: android, json, ionic-framework, ionic-native

Here my use case :

I want, when a click on a button, to save a JSON string in a file and launch a local notification. When I click on this notification, I want to open my file (previously created) to show his content in a default application.

Problem :

My function is running to save the JSON string in a file and launch the notification (I can see the string in the file manually). But, when I click on the notification, the application open the default application but the file is empty.

Here is my code that is launched when I click on the button (I download also a picture but this part is running correctly) :

```
downloadReceipt(): void {

    // Listener when I click on the notification
    this.notif.on("click", (notif) => {

        let type = notif.id == 1 ? "text/*" : "image/png";
        this.FileOpener.open(notif.data, type).then((file) => console.log("File opened : ", file)).catch((err) => console.error("Error openening : ", err));
    });

    const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    // Ask to get the anchor
    this.dbApi.getAnchorId(this.parameters.path).then((message) => {
        console.log("Get anchor ID : ", message);

        // Get the content of the anchor
        this.woleetApi.getReceipt(message['id']).then((message) => {

            let dataStr = JSON.stringify(message['content']);

            // Check if the anchor is ready
            if (message['content']['extra'] == undefined){
                this.dialogs.alert("The receipt is not yet ready")
            } else {

                // Create and save the file
                this.file.createFile(this.file.externalDataDirectory, 'receipt.json', true).then((msg) => {
                    this.file.writeExistingFile(this.file.externalDataDirectory, 'receipt.json', dataStr).then((msg) => {

                        // Launch the notification for the receipt
                        this.notif.schedule({
                            id: 1,
                            text: 'Receipt downloaded',
                            title: 'Download receipt',
                            data: this.file.externalDataDirectory + 'receipt.json'
                        });

                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.error("writeExistingFile error :", err);
                })
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.error("CreateFile error :", err);
                })


                // Download the picture
                fileTransfer.download(this.parameters.picture, this.file.externalDataDirectory + 'picture.png').then((entry) => {
                    console.log("Download complete: " + entry.toURL());

                    // Launch the notification for the picture
                    this.notif.schedule({
                        id: 2,
                        text: 'Image downloaded',
                        title: 'Download picture',
                        data: this.file.externalDataDirectory + 'picture.png'
                    })

                }).catch((err) => console.error("Error during download", err)); 

            }
        })

    })
}
```

I run this code on an Android device.

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you